# Drush: permission denied on remote server

Tags: linux, drupal, ssh, server, drush

I am trying to set `drush` up on a remote server. (a webserver by a provider)

I installed `drush` with composer via SSH, but when I try to run it, I get

```
-bash: /data/web/myusername/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush: Permission denied
```

`drush` has `-rwxr-xr-x` permissions

How would I verify if it is just the provider not allowing me to execute `drush` or simply a bug?

Edit: I found that i could run drush with `bash drush`, it seems to be a permission problem after all.

now the `drush` on my local machine would call the remote `drush` without the `bash`, so how could I change that/workaround?

Comment: when you ssh to the remote machine, what shell is used? `echo $SHELL` should tell you that. It could be that bash is not the shell when you login so you may need to see if you can set your default shell on your own, or do something like `alias drush='bash drush'` on the remote server.

Comment: hi, bash is used. If i switch to sh with `sh` I still cant run drush with `./drush` but `sh drush` works. I can reproduce that error on my local machine: If I create a script and i don't give it execution permission, i can run it with `bash script` but not with `./script`. Using alises doesn't seem to work, because my local drush as a script wont load the aliases. But yeah, I looking for something in that direction.

Comment: I suppose I'd expect a different error, but are the ~/.drush/cache permissions set correctly?

Comment: got `rwxr-xr-x` there

Comment: Hmmm... interesting. OK the only time I've seen this is when drush is not set to be executable, I know you've verified above but you might just want to check `which drush` and `ls -l ~/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush`. Sorry for redundancy but it really is the only time I've seen this error. You should also verify these permissions are set on the remote server to be executable as well.

Comment: `which` gives me no output on the remote server, for ls i get `-rwxr-xr-x `. thanks for your time btw.

Comment: now I'm stretching but do you have the following in your .bashrc file on both the local and remote machines? `export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Yes. To be clear: the drush on my local machine is working fine, its just the one on the webserver which gives me trouble. Maybe its an issue with the permissions on the lower dirs which I cannot change. Do you maybe know a workaround just like aliases?

Answer (score 7):

If still someone is facing permission issue while running drush command then run below commands
sudo chmod -R 777 /vendor/drush

Note 
Drupal 8 
Drush Commandline Tool 9.5.2

Answer (score 4):

I installed drush 8 using composer and out of the box, trying even
 `drush version`
I got "permission denied" until I did chmod + x on :

```
/vendor/bin/drush
/vendor/drush/drush
/vendor/drush/drush.launcher
```

Next, I had to override php.ini using local drush.ini with :

```
disable_functions =
```

Having any disabled funcs in the list caused drush to issue an error every time. This was on Krystal shared hosting.

Comment: This fixed my issue, adding a drush.ini and disable_functions = , for some reason when I upgraded to drush 10.3.4 from 9.7.4 I had to do this, add a drush.ini to the ~ folder (home folder in Linux/MacOSX)

Answer (score 1):

Make drush an executable:

```
chmod +x /data/web/myusername/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are centos or ubuntu user do it 
your default `/vendor/drush` permission is 755
but drush need a permission 777

```
cd /var/www/html
```

to see the permission of vendor folder

```
ll
```

here is default permission is 755

```
chmod -R 777 /vendor/drush
```

Comment: Whatever you are trying to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** You should revert to sane permissions immediately, and not touch them again until you actually understand how they work.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error output, but the problem was with the remote drush path, so also make sure you double check our script path in the alias definition:

```
'path-aliases' => array(
        '%drush-script' => 'your-server-path-here/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush'
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that drush will try to use the vendor installation if it exists.
In ProcessManager.php, method drushScript:

```
    // If the target is a local Drupal site that has a vendor/bin/drush,
    // then use that.
```

And it looks for drush in ../vendor/bin/drush.

Code here: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/11.x/src/SiteAlias/ProcessManager.php#L68

This can be very misleading because we think we're running the global drush but actually it ends up being the local drush that is being run, which can have different permissions or blocked by server security policies.